# Mitigating the duplicate content issue with SquareSpace

Tags: squarespace

I have worked a considerable amount with a customer on a SquareSpace domain recently, and have noticed that Google is indexing content at `[sitename].com` and `[sitename].squarespace.com`.

After considerable discussion with the SS support channel, I am advised that it is impossible to disable the default SquareSpace domain, and difficult to mask it - so I ask anyone with any experience in the matter, how best do I redirect all visitors (particularly Google!) to the new URI?

Comment: Have you checked with SS if it is possible to install a 301 redirect? https://www.google.ch/search?q=301 or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/301_redirect#HTTP_status_codes_3xx

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be  common problem for Squarespace users after adding a custom domain name. If Google is indexing the same content, this will result in [duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) issues, which can impact your SERP.

To prevent this from occurring, rename your user account at Squarespace to something else, since it's no longer needed with a custom domain, as covered here:  [Removing Squarespace Subdomain from Search Engine Index](http://crossplatform.net/removing-squarespace-subdomain-from-search-engine-index/)

To solve the duplicate content issues in the meantime, add a [canonical UR](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en)L to the pages that are being indexed on both domains to let Google know URL's containing your custom domain are the preferred versions.

Regarding redirecting visitors, by changing the Squarespace account as covered above, visitors will no longer see the duplicate indexed content, so there is no need to redirect them. If that is not desirable for some reason, you can create 301 redirects in your Squarespace account for each duplicate URL that is being indexed. See this for how to do that: [HOW DO I CREATE URL SHORTCUTS OR MAPPINGS?](http://help.squarespace.com/customer/portal/articles/541368-how-do-i-create-url-shortcuts-or-mappings-)

Answer (score 2):

The easy answer is to simply not share links to the "account.squarespace.com" content. Many Webmasters will post and share while still signed-into 'Admin', and this will instantly be problematic as far as *search-bots* are concerned. After creating a post, add '**testing**' to your workflow by either signing-out of admin or opening the 'domain version' of the site in another brand of browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc). Not only will you find something that needs to be edited, but once you're happy with the published work, then *blasting it to social* will be clean and simple.